# Undefined local variable or method `params' for Presenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an index view which was getting slightly bulky, so I moved all of the DB queries into a presenter to try and clean things up.

However, using params[:something] with any query makes the presenter error out with:

`undefined local variable or method params for QuestionPresenter:0x007fd6d569c158`

I have tried moving the params into helper methods in applicationcontroller, and the models but with no success.

How can i make these params available to the presenter? Or are presenters not meant to deal with such params?

Old question_controller.rb

```
def index       
   if params[:tag]
      @questions = @question.tagged_with(params[:tag]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    elsif params[:search]
      @questions = @question.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).search(params[:search])
    else
      @newest = @questions.newest.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)
      @unanswered = @question.unanswered.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2).search(params[:search])
      @votes = @question.by_votes.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2).search(params[:search])
  end 
end
```

QuestionsController.rb ( new index action)

```
def index
  @presenter = QuestionPresenter.new
end
```

question_presenter.rb

```
class QuestionPresenter
  def initialize
    @questions = Question
    @tags = Tag
  end

  def questions
    @questions.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).search(params[:search])
  end

  def tags
   @tags.joins(:taggings).select('tags.*, count(tag_id) as "tag_count"').group(:tag_id).order(' tag_count desc')
  end

  def tagged_questions
    @questions.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  end

  def newest
    @questions.newest.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
  end

  def unanswered
    @questions.unanswered.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
  end

  def votes
    @questions.by_votes.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "questions/tag_cloud", locals: {tags: @presenter.tags} %>

<% if params[:search] %> 
  <%= render partial: "questions/questions", locals: {questions: @presenter.questions} %>
<% elsif params[:tag] %>
  <%= render partial: "questions/questions", locals: {questions: @presenter.tagged_questions}%>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: "questions/tabbed_index", locals: {questions: @presenter.newest, unanswered: @presenter.unanswered, votes: @presenter.votes} %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to pass in the params hash from the controller to your QuestionPresenter:

QuestionsController.rb ( new index action)

```
def index
  @presenter = QuestionPresenter.new(params)
end
```

question_presenter.rb

```
class QuestionPresenter
  def initialize(params = {})
    @questions = Question
    @tags = Tag
    @params = params
  end

  def params
    @params
  end

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 4):

The `params` variable is accessible only from a Controller or a View.

You have to pass it to the `QuestionPresenter` in order to access it.
For example you could pass is to the `QuestionPresenter#new` method so that you got it in the `initialize` method and you can save it into an instance variable `@params` and replace everywhere in the `QuestionPresenter` class `params` by `@params`.

Comment: `params` is not a variable, it is a method with returns a HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Comment: Well in the end, @Linki showed what I was explaining, so it should be clear.